# Oracle Apex 5 LDAP search not working against global catalog

Tags: oracle, ldap, oracle-apex

In Oracle Apex, I can authenticate via LDAP if I add a very specific Distinguished Name and choose the option to use Exact Distinguished Name:

```
CN=%LDAP_USER%,OU=Office,OU=Users,OU=UKAPD,DC=rd,DC=mycompany,DC=net
```

This works.

However, I need to search across OUs and Domains, so want to use a wildcard search against the global catalogue.  Note, the above working LDAP DN is also against the global catalog on port 3268.

So If I select "No" to Use Exact Distinguished Name, then reduce my DN to be:

```
DC=mycompany,DC=net
```

and then add a search filter of:

```
CN=%LDAP_USER%
```

I get a bind failure on LDAP.

> •Authentication failed  ORA-31202: DBMS_LDAP: LDAP client/server
>   error: Operations error. 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090749, comment: In
>   order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on
>   the connection., data 0, v2580

How do I perform a global search across all domains and OUs in Oracle Apex?  There is very little documentation on this subject.  I have created via my DBA the necessary ACL in Oracle - as can be seen by my managing to succesfully authenticate when using a very specific DN string.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I see now that you specifically mentioned the Global Catalog, which I had incorrectly thought was not exposed through "normal" LDAP.

I suppose you've already read through this MS Technet article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978012.aspx
But since you don't mention it, I'll suggest a look into the use of the special NULL value as mentioned in section "Global Catalog Search Base" of that article.

Another, interesting, but maybe overmuch workaround:
https://serverfault.com/a/107368/71956

Below is my original answer, perhaps no longer valid.

> I do not believe you can do that. This is not a limitation of ApEx, but instead it is a "natural" artifact of the way LDAP works. The LDAP directory (which usually more or less corresponds to a "network domain") is stored as an independent entity, stored in its own db, with its own service processes (probably its own server host). You must have that specific "base dn" to establish the domain context for the creation of any LDAP session.
>
> I would suspect that fancy things like "domain forests" and multi-domain trusts are really handled on a back end as a loop through that list of domains with separate LDAP queries on separate LDAP sessions, each with the appropriate base dn context. I.e., there really is no such thing as a "global search" in LDAP, per se. But some nice software systems simulate it by maintaining lists of valid/trusted domains/directories and every time you ask for a global search, it just performs the search N times, once for each domain/directory.
>
> One way to (maybe) get around this: build all custom auth schemes, using PL/SQL calls to DBMS_LDAP and maintain (or maybe, possibly query) a list of valid domains to loop through on your own (just as all those other pleasant, convenient client tools have been doing for you all along).